# dropbox link to their site does not work in contextual menu nor in menu bar

Tags: macos, finder, menu-bar, dropbox, shortcut-menu

When right-clicking on a file in my dropbox folder in the finder, i get the regular window with (amongst others) the option to "view on Dropbox.com".  Clicking this link brings nothing.  Neither does clicking the world-icon in the menulet in the menu bar.
**How can i 'repair' this little imperfection?**

*(fyi: clicking the other link "Share Dropbox Link" actually does work, i have installed the newest dropbox.app on OSX 10.8.5)*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading the latest version of the Dropbox software (which can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/install) and reinstalling on your Mac?

To do this:

1. Quit Dropbox from the menubar application
2. Download the software from the Dropbox website.
3. Open the DMG file that gets downloaded
4. Double-click the "Install Dropbox" icon in the DMG file
5. Follow the instructions to reinstall Dropbox.

Comment: _Have you tried reading my question?_ ;) Dropbox is up to date. But thanks anyway for trying to help.